# Hooke force and first Newton principle, how apply it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

I have a question that maybe for this site is quite trivial, so sorry at first!

If I have a spring and a force F determines an elongation of it: the difference between the length after the application of the force and the length at rest is positive.

**My question:** if I have the value of the force applied to find out the hooke force I have to apply the first Newton principle in the point of *maximum elongation* where the hooke force balances the force F and so here the spring has null velocity?Am I right?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Is the objective to find the stiffness of the spring? The spring will generally extend until the force of the spring balances the applied force... normally you would not consider the velocity of the spring; only the steady state.

Comment: My question is: I can write $F_H-F=0\iff k(L_{fin}-L_{in})-F=0$ so there is balance (and so the spring is at rest in this position) at the point of maximum elongation right?

Comment: yes that looks correct to me - but I would not use the term "maximum elongation". I would just say that the formula defines the point of equilibrium.

Comment: you would not say since really the point of equilibrium represents the point where the spring reaches $L_fin$, right?

Comment: It seems there may be a misunderstanding of 2 issues in your question. If you DROP a mass attached to a spring it will 'bounce' in SHM (assuming no losses) with the maximum extension reached when the energy in the spring (kx^2)/2 is equal to the loss of PE of the mass, and the velocity is zero.  HOWEVER the spring constant is computed in a STATIC situation. The mass is stationary at the equilibrium point when the FORCES balance - i.e. kx =mg

Comment: ok my doubt is: this equilibrium point corresponds to the point where the length of the spring si $L_{fin}$?